# Recursion main() in Java

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, program-entry-point

I created a couple recursions of main() in Java that function correctly using a base case. Didn't think it would be possible but is calling main(args) still being handled by the JVM?

Do you have any unique main recursions?
Have you used a main() recursion in an actual application?
What are the pro's an con's to this operation?
Could this be a BigO advantage?
I believe these are O(n) time complexity.

```
//Counts to 10
public class RecursiveMain {
    static int start = 0, end = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(++start);
        if (start != end) main(args);
    }
}
```

[Outout Image - Count to 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niLce.jpg)

Output:

```
12345678910
```

```
//Reverse print array
public class RecursiveMain { // Recursive Class
    static String[] reversiSentence = {"1-explain" , "2-then" , "3-to" , "4-me" , "5-to" , "6-then" , "7-explain"}; // String Array
    static int start = 0, end = 7; // Static Base Dependants
    public static void main(String[] args) { // Recursive main() Method
        System.out.println(reversiSentence[--end]); // Print
        if (start != end) main(args); // Base Case, Recursive Invocation
    }
}
```

[Output Image - Reverse Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWIK9.jpg)

Output:

```
7-explain
6-then
5-to
4-me
3-to
2-then
1-explain
```

Comment: Take a gander at the macOS Java source code. It's written in C but the types of headaches would be similar.

Comment: Where should I start? This is a horrible idea. 1) `main(String[] args)` is meant to be called by the JVM, not by the application. Taking upon yourself to call the main method will most likely lead to many problems. Putting that aside, I have never called `main()` recursively. The pros are none IMO. The cons are many.  These problems are trivial, so you don't see them. Calling `main` recursively presents no Big-O advantage that I know of or any other advantage that I can think of. If you really want to know, modify your program to sort the array and examine the program with a profiler.

Comment: Yeah its quite interesting, main(args) is still being called by the JVM is it not? There is also a base case. I am just curious about everyone opinion, and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Can it be? Yes. It's like it's just like any other method.

As long as you declare an ending condition not to lead your program to throw `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, it will run as a charm.

But should it be? Of course not. There is not a single use case that you can show me that justifies such action.

I did fast research when writing this answer and couldn't find anyone who approved of such action.

Although it may work in your case, in general, it's not recommended by professionals, and it's not the best practice for recursion.

I propose you write your program this way:

```java
//Counts to 10
public class NotRecursiveMain {

    static int start = 0, end = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recursiveCounter(start , end);
    }

    public static void recursiveCounter(int start, int end) {
        System.out.print(start);
        if (start != end) recursiveCounter(++start, end);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
012345678910
```

```java
//Reverse print array
public class NotRecursiveMain {

    static String[] reversiSentence = {"1-explain" , "2-then" , "3-to" , "4-me" , "5-to" , "6-then" , "7-explain"}; // String Array

    public static void main(String[] args) { // Recursive main() Method
        recursiveReversePrinter(reversiSentence.length() - 1);
    }

    public static void recursiveReversePrinter(int index) {
        System.out.println(reversiSentence[index]);
        if(index != 0) recursiveReversePrinter(--index);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
7-explain
6-then
5-to
4-me
3-to
2-then
1-explain
```

Comment: Yes, I have it written correctly as well, and the recursive main examples do have a base case. I am just curious about everyone opinion, and I appreciate it.

Comment: This is basically what I wrote in the comments. These problems are trivial. Recursion is not necessary to solve. A simple loop will suffice. Recursion is mainly used when you need to work on problems that have many possible branches and computations are too complex to be done in iterations.

Comment: @BryanBlaze You are missing the point. There is zero use-case that support this type of solution in a real application. You don't get how problematic this is because your examples are extremely trivial.

Comment: Doing something like `start++` will increment `start` but it returns the **old value**. In other words, you're passing the same arguments repeatedly and this should end up with a `StackOverflowError`. You could do `++start`, but semantically it makes more sense to just do `start + 1`.